# getting data without using array for multiple entries

Tags: arrays, powershell, events, logging

we are using an array to get the data from logs, and its taking a lot of time, for it searches in all logs. we want the latest 2 logs from each sources. here is the powershell code we are using right now.

```
$arraylist = Get-Content C:\sources\sourceLFE2.csv; 
foreach($list in $arraylist)
{
$source1 = $list.Trim();

if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($source1))
{
continue;

}
if(($source1 -eq $b))
{
continue;

}
if(($source1 -eq $c))
{
continue;

}
else
{
$sourcelist = Get-EventLog -computer $computer4 -logname "lync server" -Source $source1  -EntryType "Error" ,"warning","information" -newest 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |format-table -wrap |fl  
$arraysource = $arraysource + $sourcelist; 

}
}
$arraysource | out-file -filepath $Eventfrontend;
```

this code takes input from text file i want to code these up manually to reduce time so that we get only latest 2 events for each sources mentioned in file .

How to reduce time so that the we can get the logs for real time application? Please help.

Comment: What is $b? What is $c? What does take so much time? The Get-EventLog?

Comment: ignore $b and $c for now, yes the get-eventlog command when run in loop for all the sources, takes so much time.  the sources are saved in a text file from where it gets the sources , and for each source it returns the newest event. can't we do something where by the machine jumps to second element in array once it gets the first entry ? instead of searing in whole event viewer? I know this can be done easily but since I am not good in programming so I dont know how to accomplish this.

Answer (score -1):

This should work better

```
$arraysource = @()

$arraylist = Get-Content C:\sources\sourceLFE2.csv; 

foreach($list in $arraylist)

{

$source1 = $list.Trim()

if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($source1)) { continue }

if(($source1 -eq $b)) { continue }

if(($source1 -eq $c)) { continue }

$arraysource += Get-EventLog -computer $computer4 -logname "lync server" -Source $source1  -EntryType "Error" ,"warning","information" -newest 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |format-table -wrap |fl  

}

$arraysource | out-file -filepath $Eventfrontend
```

Comment: is it going to be faster? since the command works fine but takes longer than it should to be used in real time application.